# Resources matching LABiometryType

Tags: ios, icons, touch-id, face-id

I want to provide application login using TouchID or FaceID. If the authentication fails, users should have the option to enter their credentials manually or to re-try authentication.

I would like to present retry option as a button that shows the icon of the authentication method - the fingerprint for TouchID and the smiling face for FaceID (similar to 1Password's UI).

Is there a way to get such an icon out of the system? SF Symbols contains a FaceID icon, but I haven't found one for TouchID.

**Note:** I am aware that the [HIG recommends](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/user-interaction/authentication/) that I should *not* use such icons, but both me and the product owner disagree with this specific guideline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SF Symbols 2 contains a TouchID icon as well. Both TouchID and FaceID have a clause "This symbol may not be modified and may only be used to refer to Apple's Toch ID (Face ID) feature.", but this is okay for me.